# Pop-up and Compound menu control in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am making an iphone app in which i want to make a form which involves using pop-up's or compound menu control. I have found these terms as i was googling something like this, but i didn't find any example or sample code explaining that how it can be done.

Please tell me something about it, if possible, with a sample code.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want a pop up to open. and what do you mean by compound menu. Please Elaborate.

Comment: Please take a look at the following link :
   http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/11/forms-on-mobile-devices-modern-solutions/
I have got the idea from this link.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use customized uipopovercontroller for iPhone..

Comment: UIPopOverController is for iPad not for iPhone.

Comment: How can i do that. Is there any tutorial for it as i have seen it only in case of ipad.

Comment: yes there is a way to implement customized uipopovercontroller like control.. basically its a view so we can create a uiview and can dismiss it when user taps outside of the view.. inside that view you can integrate uitableview. thats it..

Comment: Thanks nik for the information, but my question is how can i implement popup menu or compound menu as described in the link : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/11/forms-on-mobile-devices-modern-solutions/ as i am trying to make a form in iphone app.

Comment: its a uipickerview controller check this sample code for implementation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html